# Why is it more recommended to use dynamic over static classes in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, inversion-of-control

I'm in need of some clarification on how why it is more recommeded to use dynmaic classes rather than static ones. Laravel's documentation uses a lot of examples which use DI to inject objects... But sometimes Laravel uses static methods or classes.

My question is, for every request, everything is reset, right? So using static classes is just as good as dynamic in that case? - I know this is probably wrong but I am failing to understand why...

For example, Laravel allows you to pass in an object inside the constructor but why not just use a static class instead? Why use a dynamic class when you only use it once for the request in the Controller example? I am just trying to understand why, I am not trying to justify my understanding.

Comment: You might want to [read up on OOP](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/object-oriented-programming-concepts-21bb035f7260) to understand that objects (dynamic classes as you call them) hold state. Also Laravel will make you a little more confused as [Facades](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/facades) are static classes that will behave like objects (singletons to be precise).

Comment: A thing to consider. It's nearly impossible to mock static classes which makes testing a lot harder.

Comment: Can you provide a reference about these "dynamic" or "static" classes?

Comment: @apokryfos Sometimes I see the Laravel docs use Crypt:: for example but then other classes get passed in via the constructor? How come?

Comment: Laravel uses [Facades](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/facades) which are (in short) proxies to singleton objects.